# Passing string argument that points to variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api v3 javascript.  I have a list of buttons, and I need them to pan the map to a new marker.  Each location is set up:

```
var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(61.21444507411448,-149.8841142654419);
var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(61.21179982469673,-149.89338397979736);
var location3 = new google.maps.LatLng(61.21580894399659,-149.88239765167236);
```

The map works fine, its all set up with markers and everything.  Now to load the new location, theres the pan to function:

```
map.panTo(thelocation);
```

I could pass the variable directly, and google maps reads it.  But what happens when I make a click function for one of the buttons, and use the id tag with same name as location var, it cannot read it, because its not reading the data in the location var, its reading the string located in the id:

```
$(".listing").click(function() {
    console.log("you clicked on a listing!");
    var location = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(location);
})
```

I need to put the panTo function in the listing click function, and have it pan to the right location based on which listing they clicked on.
Theres probably more than one way to do this.  I want to use the id of the listing clicked on (which is same id as the latlng variable), and have panTo read the data stored in var location1 (or 2, 3, etc). Not read it as a string.
How can I do this?  I know in bash, its something like `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it, the best way is to use an object to hold the values. You can use the id as the key and just reference it.

```
var details = { 
    location1 : new google.maps.LatLng(61.21444507411448,-149.8841142654419),
    location2 : new google.maps.LatLng(61.21179982469673,-149.89338397979736),
    location3 : new google.maps.LatLng(61.21580894399659,-149.88239765167236)
};

$(".listing").on("click", function() {
    var loc = this.id;
    console.log(details[loc]);
});
```

Comment: Google maps does it like this in an example here: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sidebar/random-markers.html

Comment: @DavidProvost AND Eval is a bad idea... bad solution you picked.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript also has an eval function, so you could parse your string variable to point the actual latlng variable by using eval to a new function:

```
$(".listing").click(function() {
    console.log("you clicked on a listing!");
    var location = $(this).attr('id');
    var goLocation = eval(location);
    console.log(location);
    console.log(goLocation);
    map.panTo(goLocation);
})
```

But if your interested in security, you may opt for another solution:
Exerpt from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Don't use `eval` needlessly!

`eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which `eval()` was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar [`Function`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is not susceptible.

`eval()` is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.

There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to `eval()` for common use-cases.

Comment: EVAL IS BAD>>>>YIKES , why would you pick this? It is a bad bad practice.

Comment: He mentioned eval in his question, so I informed him it does exist in javascrip too, but I also gave the warning.